# Can't print (No Drivers found)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing

### Translation

Hello, I have had serious printing problems. Did not think that most printers don't work in Ubuntu. I changed operating system with the will to learn more about Linux seen as I have always worked with Microsoft, whom I am really sick off with so much exclusivity with anything, including manufacturers and dealers.

There are several printers in this company like the Kyocera 1016, 1820, TM-U series and HP scanners. With the scanners I already made them work with xsane but still having problems with Kyocera and TMU. I have installed the generic TMU drivers, even in RAW and it has been impossible to print out the receipt. I tried giving the LP port permissions but it won't allow me. I have looked for the drivers in Internet with no luck.

What can I do because, either there are no drivers for this type of printers or because they are very rare to find. I think that Ubuntu is a great OS, although it would be even greater and I would be very grateful if this printers worked. I started this project in this company because my boss has no Microsoft Licenses, not even for the Office suite and Linux is the best choice since it is free.

Thanks, Pablo

### Original

Hola, he tenido serio problemas con las impresoras. No pense que en Ubuntu la mayoria de las impresoras no funcionaran. He cambiado a este sistema con animo de aprender mas de Linux ya que siempre he trabajado con Microsoft, el cual me tiene hasta el tope con tanta exclusividad para todo, incluso hasta con los proveedores y fabricantes.

Hay varios tipos de impresoras en esta empresa como la Kyocera 1016, 1820, TM-U...series y scanners HP.  Ya con el scanner logre que trabajara con xsane super bien, pero la Kyocera y las TMU no. He instalado las TMU como genericas, tambien en RAW y ha sido imposible que salga la factura. Trato de darle permiso al puerto LP y tampoco deja, he buscado controladores para Linux en internet pero definitivamente me ha sido imposible.

Que puedo hacer porque no existen drivers para este tipo de impresoras o bien porque casi no se consiguen. Me parece que Ubuntu es un buen SO, aunque si es posible lograr imprimir o hacer funcionar correctamente a estas impresoras les estaria agradecido. Inicie este proyecto en esta empresa porque el jefe no tiene licencias de Microsoft, ni de office para nada y Linux es la mejor opcion ya que es libre.

Gracias, Pablo

Comment: Voy a corregir los horrores ortograficos pero proxima vez Pablo tomate un momentico en escribir mejor ya que cuesta mucho entender el problema. Tambien voy a pasarlo al ingles para que puedas recibir mas ayuda. Saludos.

Going to translate the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The only useful information I found was dated back to 2007 talking about problems with the Kyocera. Since then there were several fixes which you can find in the following links:

Driver - http://sourceforge.net/projects/kyo-fs1016mfp/

Information - http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Kyocera/Kyocera-FS-1016MFP (Actually the only 1016 model I found)

Information - http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Kyocera/Kyocera-KM-1820

Printing Database - http://www.openprinting.org/printers (So you can check the rest of them. I am pretty sure all of them work except the TMU which might actually be a typo and it might be TM.)

---

La unica informacion util que encontre fue de 2007 donde hablaban de un problema con la Kyocera. Desde entonces se han reparado varios problemas. Aqui te dejo los siguientes links que te ayudaran:

Controladora - http://sourceforge.net/projects/kyo-fs1016mfp/

Informacion - http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Kyocera/Kyocera-FS-1016MFP (La unica 1016 que encontre)

Informacion - http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Kyocera/Kyocera-KM-1820

Base de Datos de Impresoras - http://www.openprinting.org/printers (Asi puedes chequear tu mismo las demas que tengas en la empresa. Estoy seguro que funcionaran todas excepto la TMU. Si en realidad es TM entonces tambien apareceran en la lista.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be solved by having one Windows printer server on which printers can be installed , and it will work on Linux with NoLinDrivers printer server, you can read full tutorial about how to print from linux WITHOUT needing any linux printer drivers or PPDs here: http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-print-from-linux-without-needing.html